# SQL Server : filtered rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filtered

I get below Table A using

```
select sn, processName, result
from xxxx
inner join xxxx on xxxx
inner join xxxx on xxxx
where processDate between xxx  xxx
```

Table A

| sn | processName | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a01 | depthMeas | 0.1 |
| a01 | widthMeas | 2 |
| a01 | weight | 11.6 |
| b02 | depthMeas | 0.2 |
| b02 | widthMeas | 2.1 |
| b02 | weight | 11.3 |
| a24 | depthMeas | 0.15 |
| a24 | widthMeas | 2.2 |
| a24 | weight | 11.5 |

How can I transform Table A or directly get table like below?

| sn | depthMeas | widthMeas | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a01 | 0.1 | 2.0 | 11.6 |
| b02 | 0.2 | 2.1 | 11.3 |
| a24 | 0.15 | 2.2 | 11.5 |

Probably I can transform it using where clause and pivot. But it will have to be ran multiple (3 times) of query which will take long time (since my records are around 350,000,000)

Power BI, I am loading 3 times of native query table.

1. 'depthMeas' filtered table
2. 'widthMeas' filtered table
3. 'weight' filtered table.

and then merge them into one table. This takes bunch of times on native query process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You might get some useful ideas from [SQL Server 2012 Vertical data to Horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58627285/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`, as in:

```
with
q as (
  -- your query here
)
select
  sn,
  max(case when processname = 'depthMeas' then result end) as depthmeas,
  max(case when processname = 'widthMeas' then result end) as widthmeas,
  max(case when processname = 'weight' then result end) as weight
from q
group by sn
```